# How to use headers in Unix Network Programming

Tags: c, unix

I was going through the classic book [Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139498761),I meet a problem which is about compile.
  e.g. I can compile correctly the source code which is /home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/tcpserv01.c. after I copy it to /home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c and make test.c,  it reminds me error as the below shows.

```
/tmp/ccI4xfzr.o: In function `main':
```

/home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c:11: undefined reference to `Socket'
/home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c:18: undefined reference to`Bind'
/home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c:20: undefined reference to `Listen'
/home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c:21: undefined reference to`Signal'
/home/yuhongsong/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c:31: undefined reference to `Close'
/home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c:24: undefined reference to`Accept'
/home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c:26: undefined reference to `Fork'
/home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c:27: undefined reference to`Close'
/home/song/unpv13e/tcpcliserv/test.c:28: undefined reference to `str_echo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1

The function name begins with a capital letter is defined in "unp.h". where do the problem arises,how to solve it,and how to use the header suitablely.
 the source code shows as below:

```
#include "unp.h"
#include "sigchldwait.c"

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 listenfd, connfd;
    pid_t               childpid;
    socklen_t           clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in  cliaddr, servaddr;


    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(SERV_PORT);

    Bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
        Signal(SIGCHLD, sig_chld);
    for ( ; ; ) {
        clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &clilen);

        if ( (childpid = Fork()) == 0) {    /* child process */
            Close(listenfd);    /* close listening socket */
            str_echo(connfd);   /* process the request */
            exit(0);
        }
        Close(connfd);          /* parent closes connected socket */
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think things have evolved a tiny bit since 1990? If not socket programming, then definitively the C language. Anyway, provide a [mcve] and **all** required information.

Comment: Oh, and format your code properly. There is an `edit` link under your text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linkage problem, you nee to link against this lib.

You probably compiled correctly against this lib (using the header) but you did not give the lib at lib time.

It si possible that you even need to compile it if you get it from sources.

Comment: Thank you. I also find this problem a time later.But I don`t know how to describe it. You are a good man.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that defaultly make test.c is equal to `gcc -I../lib -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall   -c -o test.o test.c`.But test.c need a static library where the function e.g. Accept come from.